# On a HTTP server, why must the permission attributes on a user’s public_html directory be set to: execute by all?

Tags: html, linux, http

I am new to Linux and have been searching for a good resource to try and understand this, but can't find anywhere that explains it clearly. an example of the permission is drwx--x--x. Does anyone know why the attributes must be that way?

Comment: Without details of your http server setup and configuration nobody will be able to help you. I can however tell you that that do not need to be set that way.

Comment: I'm not actually setting one up, it's a general question as to why http public_html permission attributes must be set that way.

Comment: They need not be. It all depends on the user/group of the process(es) which need access to it, which depend on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Execute permissions on a directory permit accessing of the directory contents.

[RUTE - Permission and Modification Times](https://rlworkman.net/howtos/rute/node17.html)

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand, are you saying it's so all users can access directory contents?

Comment: User permissions affect the user owner, group permissions affect the group owner, other permissions affect everyone else.